# using HBase instead of HDFS in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

Scenario:

I analyze terabytes of data and do some text mining on top of that and store the data into HDFS files. Then to query the data we import this data into Hive.

However we also need to perform some update operations on incremental data. For example,  if the same rowkey exists in new and old data, then update the data rather than insert.

Currently I am doing the above operations using HDFS. Now I am thinking of moving into HBase with read/write operations.

I want to know the performance pros and cons of this approach 
of using HBase read/write with MapReduce in comparison to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Pros(Using HBase as data store):

- Flexible data model to work with and data is indexed by the row key.
- Fast scans across tables.
- Low latency access to small amounts of data from within a large data
  set. You can access single rows quickly from a billion row table.
- For small updates it is better because you can scan and update rather
  than append(which is case with HDFS).

Cons(Using HBase as data store):

- you need to perform bulk load in order to load the bulk data(tera
  bytes) in your case.
- using bulk load will skip WAL(with risk of data loss).
- in case if you do not perform bulk load for data loading, speed will
  decrease.

I hope I have answered your question.
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Addition to this answer, if you use all of your data in hdfs every time you ran a mapreduce job, it would be sloooow reading all data every time from hbase compared to hfds txt or parquet files

Comment: @halil Are you supporting hbase or hdfs. your comment  was bit ambiguous.

Comment: @RamPrasadG i dont support either of two because i dont know the use case. If you need to filter your data for mapreduce then hbase may help, if you read all your data or daily/hourly all data for every mapreduce, then reading all data from hbase is slow compared to hdfs.